# Imap Mail : AE.NET.Mail Body Of Emails Are Empty

Tags: c#, email, .net-4.0

I use AE.NET.Mail to read my emails body.
but all those bodies are empty!
my codes are like below :

```
    // Connect to the IMAP server. The 'true' parameter specifies to use SSL
    // which is important (for Gmail at least)
    ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.soscharge.com", "main@domain.tk", "123",
                    ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 143, false);
    // Select a mailbox. Case-insensitive
    ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
    Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount());
    // Get the first *11* messages. 0 is the first message;
    // and it also includes the 10th message, which is really the eleventh ;)
    // MailMessage represents, well, a message in your mailbox
    MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10);
    foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
    {
        Response.Write(m.Sender + "<br /><br />");
    }
    foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
    {
        Response.Write(m.Sender + "<br /><br />");
    }
    // Probably wiser to use a using statement
    ic.Dispose();
```

my emails are utf-8 encoded.
what is the problem and how can i grab those bodies?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a default argument in the GetMessages() method for "headersonly" which by default is true, when specified as false the body of the message is downloaded:

```
        using (ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 
                    "anemail@example.org", 
                    "PasswordGoesHere!", 
                    ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 
                    993, true))
        {
            ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
            Console.WriteLine(ic.ListMailboxes("",""));

            // Note that you must specify that headersonly = false
            // when using GetMesssages().
            MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10, false);

            foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.From);
                Console.WriteLine(m.Body);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have some squares for some bodies. how can i fix that?

Comment: Would need to see an example, but sounds like it might be a character set issue.

Comment: @JamesWarne It throwing exception as "System.OutOfMemoryException" when reading message from draft Folder

Comment: @khushbu I believe that should be a separate question.